# MATLAB User-Defined Classes Memory Usage

Tags: matlab, oop, memory

I was playing around with Object-Oriented Programming in MATLAB and stumbled into the following situation. In order to create a variable of 7,6 mb (information provided by the `whos` function), MATLAB needs to allocate forty times more (information provided by the `memory` function). What is the explanation for that?

Class:

```
classdef test_object
    properties
        a
        b
        c
        d
    end
    methods
        function T = test_object(m,n)
            if nargin > 0
                if isa(m,'test_object')
                    T = m;
                elseif isa(m,'double')
                    for i = (m*n):(-1):1
                        T(i).a = '0';
                        T(i).b = '0';
                        T(i).c = '0';
                        T(i).d = '0';
                    end
                    T = reshape(T,m,n);
                end
            else
                T.a = '0';
                T.b = '0';
                T.c = '0';
                T.d = '0';
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Tester:

```
mega = 1024^2;

minit = memory;
fprintf('Memory usage before object creation: %g mb\n',minit.MemUsedMATLAB/mega);

%

a = test_object(1000,1000);

minit = memory;
fprintf('Memory usage after object creation: %g mb\n',minit.MemUsedMATLAB/mega);

whos_a = whos("a");
fprintf('whos object: %g mb\n',whos_a.bytes/mega);

%

clear a

minit = memory;
fprintf('Memory usage after object deletion: %g mb\n',minit.MemUsedMATLAB/mega);
```

Result:

```
Memory usage before object creation: 1591.14 mb
Memory usage after object creation: 1892.49 mb
whos object: 7.62939 mb
Memory usage after object deletion: 1587.46 mb
```

Comment: I don't think you can rely on memory usage reports to make guesses about the size of objects in memory. But also `whos` provides incomplete size information. You created 1 million arrays, assuming there's no data sharing, these arrays will occupy 120 bytes each. Your object itself takes up some space as well. If I create a struct identical to your object, but without it being an object, `whos` reports 456000256 bytes. That is 456 bytes per value.

Comment: `T(1e6).a='0'; [T.a]=deal('0'); [T.b]=deal('0'); [T.c]=deal('0'); [T.d]=deal('0'); whos`

Comment: I think the `whos` function always supposes that there is no data sharing. Anyway, I knew that the value provided by whos was conservative because it was only informing 8 bytes per (1,1) object element (2 bytes per char times 4 char-properties per element). But I definitely wasn't expecting that the underlining object information would explode this value to way more than ten times. Following your nice idea of exploring an equivalent struct, it was possible to infer that its size is about `456 * n + 256` bytes where n is the number of elements.

Comment: Indeed, `whos` assumes no data sharing, it just adds up the space occupied by each array stored in the struct. An array header takes up 112 bytes (not 120 as I said earlier), and an array with a single value stores that value in the header itself. Nevertheless, `whos` reports 120 bytes for a single-element array contained in a cell array (`{1}`). I presume it is mindlessly doing "112 + number of array elements * size of array element". It never reports the additional 112 bytes of the main array header: compare `a=1; b={1}; whos`.

Comment: Anyway, it looks like `whos` is reporting "4 * (array header + 1 array element * 2 bytes)" = 456 bytes for each object element. A 'char' is 2 bytes.

Comment: Hahaha. Only now I got it. I was naively expecting the same behavior of `a=zeros(1000,1000); b={a}; whos`. And that is utterly wrong. Basically we have an array of pointers so at best we have "number of properties * pointer size" per object element. I feel really embarrassed for that. Anyway, thank you for your time!